# grails hibernateQuery count

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

I don't know if this query is possible using grails *executeQuery*. I made sample a domain class:

```
class Child {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String nickName
}
```

and here is my boot strap:

```
class BootStrap {

def init = { servletContext ->

    def childOne = new Child(firstName: 'Poliwag', lastName:'Wrath', nickName: 'taurus')
    def childTwo = new Child(firstName: 'Poliwarp', lastName: 'Wrath', nickName:'libra')
    def childThree = new Child(firstName: 'Poliwag', lastName: 'Wrath',nickName:'aries')
    def childFour = new Child(firstName: 'Poliwag', lastName: 'Wrath',nickName:'virgo')

    childOne.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    childTwo.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    childThree.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    childFour.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)        
    }

}
```

as you notice, i have 2 sample data entries that have the same *firstName* & *lastName* property, they only differ in *nickName* property. What I want to get in *executeQuery* is a list of entry whose *firstName* & *lastName* properties is the same from another 2 entries. is it possible to use an operator with count(...) in grails *executeQuery*? I think this is the equivalent code for this using dynamic finders:

```
def list = []
def c = Child.countByFirstNameAndLastName('Poliwag',Wrath)
if (c == 2) {
    list.add(Child.findByFirstNameAndLastName('Poliwag','Wrath'))
}
```

I think it will save more lines of code if I use *executeQuery* if possible.
thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the nickname and lastname are fixed values like in your example you can use regular WHERE condition and SELECT COUNT in executeQuery which is the same as countBy method you used.

But if these values are not fixed, you can use GROUP BY and HAVING to accomplish this. But that way you can not return the whole object, only the attributes you are grouping by:

```
def c = Child.executeQuery("select new map(c.firstname as firstname, c.lastname as lastname) from Child c group by c.firstname, c.lastname having count(c.firstname) = 2")
```

You can iterate through the result map like this:

```
c.each{
    println it.firstname + " " + it.lastname
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, just have a follow up question.
what I did is this:
    def c = Child.executeQuery("select new map(c.firstName as firstname, c.lastName as lastname) from Child c group by c.firstName, c.lastName having count(c.firstName) = 3 and count(c.lastName) = 4")

It only returned a _null_ list, I expected it will return data entry that has the same first name with another 2 entries and has the same last name with another 3 entries.

Comment: GROUP BY statement works in a way that it creates groups with columns you specified and AFTER that HAVING statement operates on the set that GROUP BY returns. So instead of writing 'having count(c.firstname=2) I could also write having count(c.lastname)=2 and I would get the same result. You can look at this example to understand it better if I am not clear: http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_group_by2.php

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by doing some thing like this.

```
def x = Child.executeQuery("select c1 from Child c1,Child c2 where c1.firstName=c2.firstName and c1.nickName<>c2.nickName")

println x.size()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def x = Child.executeQuery("select count (*) from Child c1,Child c2 where c1.firstName=c2.firstName and c1.nickName<>c2.nickName")

println x[0]
```